# Is there a way to return user rating of a one book for that user?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, entity, httpresponse

I am working on a project, trying to create an AudioBook website. I am stuck on this part and i cant find answers on the internet.

The problem is when i get user, and list of favorite books, each book has list of user rating, from all of the users. And also there is a list of UserRatings that contains all of ratings from that user. I dont want neither.

Basically, is there a way to make it so when i do a search for list of books, every book object contains UserRating(One user rating) from a specific User that is logged in?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_rating")
public class user_rating {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Integer Id;

    @Column
    private String rating;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private users user;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    private books book;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class users {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "date_of_creation")
    private java.sql.Date dateOfCreation;

    @Column
    private String password;


    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "favourites",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<books> favourites = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="user")
    private List<user_rating> UserRating = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class books {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "date_of_creation")
    private java.sql.Date date_of_creation;

    @Column
    private String text_file;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favourites")
    private Set<users> users = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private audio_file audioFile;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<user_rating> UserRatings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I don't think that you can make it automatic as such a relation does not exist in the database, but you can always obtain the rating for the current user and the book by getting the current user id from the session and the book id.